# Find $a$ and $m$ for a given $x$ so that $ax≡1(mod(m))$

Tags: modular-arithmetic

When the $\gcd(a,m)=1$, we know that $ax≡1\mod(m)$ does have an inverse in $m$. 
Normally $a$ and $m$ are given and $x$ must be found. How can I find $a$ and $m$ when only $x $ is given so that $ax≡1(\mod(m))$?

For example when I choose $x=1337$ one solution would be $36290x=1(\mod (48519729))$.

Comment: Take any $a$ you like, compute $ax-1$, and let $m$ be any divisor of that.

Comment: Take $a=1$ and $m=x-1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take any $a\neq 0$ you like, and let $m$ be any divisor of $ax-1$.

For example, with $x=1337$, take $a=731$, note that $$731\times 1337-1=977346 = 2\times 3^5\times 2011$$  and we might take $m=2011$ or we could take $m= 977346$ and so on.

Comment: Will there always be an $m≠1$ ?

Comment: Of course, since $ax-1$ is not always $1$.

Answer (score 0):

If $x$ is given, let$ a=1 $and$ m=x-1$ is also solution to this question. We can find many values of $m$ and$ a$